# Rich interaction in Java/JSP web app

Tags: hibernate, jsp, user-interface, struts, user-experience

I'm writing a website in JSP using Struts and Hibernate. I'm looking for a way to implement a rich UI where you can have more than just buttons. For examples, drag and drops, drop down lists that updates itself in real time as you type more letters out etc. Is there a way to use something like Swing with Struts and Hibernate? Or are there any other options available for making a rich UI?? (I'm open to abandon Struts and/or Hibernate if there are better alternatives)

**Fundamental problem:** The organization I work for have strict rules about what development tools and open source libraries we can or cannot use, and is pretty slow on updating their approval list. None of the AJAX things (e.g. GWT, dojo) are on the list yet.

*Thank you for taking the time to read this post!*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, the use of Struts and Hibernate has no impact on the interactivity of the UI, because both of those are server-side technologies.

Unless you can use a technology like GWT, OpenLaszlo or Flex, the only way you`ll be able to achieve a rich user interface is by writing it yourself in raw JavaScript. This would be a lot easier if you can persuade your organisation to allow you to use a JavaScript library such as JQuery or Prototype.

Answer (score 0):

You can always use things like Adobe Flex for your UI pieces and have a java-based backend for it...

How about that new JavaFX tech?   IceFaces or RichFaces (JSF)?

Comment: JSF is supported only through one of struts tag libraries called "struts-faces". We have struts 1.3.5--it's pretty old and doesn't have rich UI capabilities. Unfortunately, none of the above are supported. It's a bit frustrating to work with what I have. Guess I'm stuck. Thank you though.